# How do you do this in C# without using List?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops

I am new to C#.  The following code was a solution I came up to solve a challenge.  I am unsure how to do this without using List since my understanding is that you can't push to an array in C# since they are of fixed size.

Is my understanding of what I said so far correct?

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve creating a new array every time I need to add to an array?  If there is no other way, how would I create a new array when the size of the array is unknown before my loop begins?

> Return a sorted array of all non-negative numbers less than the given n which are divisible both by 3 and 4. For n = 30, the output should be

**threeAndFour(n) = [0, 12, 24].**

```
int[] threeAndFour(int n) {
  List<int> l = new List<int>(){ 0 };

  for (int i = 12; i < n; ++i)
    if (i % 12 == 0)
      l.Add(i);

  return l.ToArray();
}
```

***EDIT:*** I have since refactored this code to be..

```
int[] threeAndFour(int n) {
  List<int> l = new List<int>(){ 0 };

  for (int i = 12; i < n; i += 12)
      l.Add(i);

  return l.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: (n / 12) + 1 is the size required for your array.

Comment: It is true that arrays are fixed size. And lists are little more then wrappers around arrays, to have them grow automagically. List can also be transformed into a array via ToArray(). The only other way to make a collection that can grow I could think off, would be a linked list. But those are useless outside of very specific circumstances.

Comment: Fun fact. 'List` is nothing more then a management wrapper around an array (if the array is full they double the size and copy all elements over). However if you want different data structures that can handle adding an unkown amount of elements without using an array you could take a look at linked lists (basically each item is wrapped in a wrapper that points to the next item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A. Lists is OK

If you want to use a `for` to find out the numbers, then `List` is the appropriate data structure for collecting the numbers as you discover them.

## B. Use more maths

```
static int[] threeAndFour(int n) {
  var a = new int[(n / 12) + 1];
  for (int i = 12; i < n; i += 12) a[i/12] = i;
  return a;
}
```

## C. Generator pattern with `IEnumerable<int>`

I know that this doesn't return an array, but it does avoid a list.

```
static IEnumerable<int>  threeAndFour(int n) {
  yield return 0;

  for (int i = 12; i < n; i += 12)
      yield return i;
}
```

## D. Twist and turn to avoid a list

The code could `for` twice. First to figure the size or the array, and then to fill it.

```
int[] threeAndFour(int n) {
  // Version: A list is really undesirable, arrays are great.
  int size = 1;
  for (int i = 12; i < n; i += 12)
      size++;
  var a = new int[size];
  a[0] = 0;
  int counter = 1;
  for (int i = 12; i < n; i += 12) a[counter++] = i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my question if there a way to do this with only using an array.
You also provided alternatives as well which is great.  Answer **D** is how you do this with only using an array.  The only thing you left out was to `return a;`

Answer (score 1):

`if (i % 12 == 0)`

So you have figured out that the numbers which divides both 3 and 4 are precisely those numbers that divides 12.

Can you figure out how many such numbers there are below a given `n`? - Can you do so without counting the numbers - if so there is no need for a dynamically growing container, you can just initialize the container to the correct size.

Once you have your array just keep track of the next index to fill.

Comment: Yes, the lowest common denominator, which is 12 here.  The only way I can think of how many numbers there are below a given **n** is to run a loop an increment an int variable and then use that to assign the length of a new array.  Is that correct?  If so, then just create the new array with all elements of 0 and then reassign the value in the following loop?

Comment: @Milliorn That is not correct.  It should be easy for you to answer how many non-negative numbers less than 12000000000000 divides 12.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq and [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) method for the purpose. For example,

```
int[] threeAndFour(int n) 
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0,n).Where(x=>x%12==0).ToArray();

}
```

`Enumerable.Range` generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range, which is then filtered on the condition `(x%12==0)` to retrieve the desired result.

Comment: I love one line solutions but this fails the test.

Input:
n: 30
Output:
[12, 24]
Expected Output:
[0, 12, 24]

Comment: @Milliorn Please check the updated answer .Just realized you require 0 as well

Comment: Yes your refactor now passes the test.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know this goes in steps of 12 and you know how many there are before you start, you can do:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,n/12+1).Select(x => x*12).ToArray();
```

Comment: Two previous posters mentioned something similar to this.  Is there a reason like with complexity that you wrote it this way versus how the other two wrote this?

```    return Enumerable.Range(0,n).Where(x=>x%12==0).ToArray();

Comment: @Milliorn It's more efficient: generating numbers you know will not be divisible is somewhat pointless. But agreed, in this case where the operation is trivial and the divisors are small, it's not enough of a performance difference to worry about and maybe you want a solution that reads more like the problem. Now, if it was selecting records from a database maybe you'd need to worry more about efficiency ...

Answer (score 1):

`List` generally works pretty well, as I understand your question you have challenged yourself to solve a problem without using the List class. An array (or List) uses a contiguous block of memory to store elements. Arrays are of fixed size.  List will dynamically expand to accept new elements but still keeps everything in a single block of memory.

You can use a linked list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8 to produce a simulation of an array.  A linked list allocates additional memory for each element (node) that is used to point to the next (and possibly the previous). This allows you to add elements without large block allocations, but you pay a space cost (increased use of memory) for each element added. The other problem with linked lists are you can't quickly access random elements. To get to element 5, you have to go through elements 0 through 4. There's a reason arrays and array like structures are favored for many tasks, but it's always interesting to try to do common things in a different way.

Comment: I was unaware of LinkedList until now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I am unsure how to do this without using List since my understanding is that you can't push to an array in C# since they are of fixed size.

It is correct that arrays can not grow. List were invented as a wrapper around a array that automagically grows whenever needed. Note that you can give List a [integer via the Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor), wich will tell it the *minimum* size it should expect. It will allocate at least that much the first time. This can limit growth related overhead.

And dictionaries are just a variation of the list mechanics, with Hash Table key search speed.

There is only 1 other Collection I know of that *can* grow. However it is rarely mentioned outside of theory and some very specific cases:

[Linked Lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). The linked list has a unbeatable growth performance and the lowest issue of running into OutOfMemory Exceptions due to Fragmentation. Unfortunately, their random access times are the worst as a result. Unless you can process those collections exclusively sequentally from the start (or sometimes the end), their performance will be abysmal. Only stacks and queues are likely to use them. There is however still a implementation you could use in .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1

Your code holds some potential too:

```
  for (int i = 12; i < n; ++i)
    if (i % 12 == 0)
      l.Add(i);
```

It would way more effective to count up by 12 every itteration - you are only interested in every 12th number after all. You may have to change the loop, but I think a do...while would do. Also the array/minimum List size is easily predicted: Just divide n by 12 and add 1. But I asume that is mostly mock-up code and it is not actually that deterministic.

Comment: Thank for some clarification to my questions.  If this really is the best way to go about this with List then yes I agree that refactoring the conditions in the loop to eliminate the if statement would be best.  It would cut down a lot of work.

Comment: @Milliorn With these values, the computational load would literally be cut by 12. However I would give it a 50/50 chance that the Compiler Optimisations and JiT compiler had already figured that out. So there might be no practical speed increase.

Comment: After reading your comment I came up with this refactor.
`int[] threeAndFour(int n) {
  List<int> l = new List<int>(){ 0 };
  
  for (int i = 12; i < n; i += 12)
      l.Add(i);
  
  return l.ToArray();
}`

Comment: @Milliorn That is even better what I had in my mind. No need for that division by 12. | If the value of 12 is deterministic too, there is a even slightly faster way: Have the whole list precalculated in memory. Only ever make "printouts" up to a certain index from it. But I am unsure that would still be worth the coding effort you would have to do. Particulary putting it into code, generating it on startup or reading it from a file might be more trouble then it is worth.